# VSTS Rest API queries for linked work items in Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, azure-devops

Using REST APIs of VSTS in `PowerShell`, I wanted to create a report on my VSTS Team Project which consists of the details of the Work Item Linking relationships of all workitems under particular "Iteration Path" and "Area Path".

Ex: `Epics→Features→UserStories`. Since there are parent/child relationships between Epics & Features and also between Features & UserStories.

So the input would be `Iteration Path` and `Area Path`, and the corresponding output would be a report (.csv or .xls) which has all the details of these workitems and their relationships.

Could someone let me know on how to achieve this using REST APIs in PowerShell?

I wrote the code for getting the hierarchical workitems in a Team Project but need to modify to filter the the list based on a given Iteration and Area paths.
Also when executing the below code, the string comparison in the query(due to presence of '') is returning an error in the power-shell.

**Error:** Invoke-RestMethod : {"count":1,"value":{"Message":"After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: G.
Path 'query', line 1, position 163.\r\n"}}

```
$vstsAccount = "xxxx"
$projectName = "xxxx"
$user = "xxxx"
$token = "xxxx"

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

# Construct the REST URL to obtain Build ID
$uri = "https://$($vstsAccount).visualstudio.com/$($projectName)/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0"

$body = "{'query': 'Select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State] From WorkItemLinks WHERE 
((Source.[System.TeamProject] = '$projectName' and Source.[System.State] <> 'Removed') and (Source.[System.WorkItemType] = 'Epic') and
([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') and (Target.[System.WorkItemType] = 'UserStory') mode(Recursive)'}"

# Invoke the REST call and capture the results (notice this uses the POST method)
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $body
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've done the basic investigation or even given this a try yourself? Someone would be unlikely to post a full solution for you. How about you give it a go yourself and post back for assistance filling in the blanks?

Comment: Do you solve the issue with my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify part of your code like this:

```
$query = "Select
    [System.Id],
    [System.WorkItemType],
    [System.Title],
    [System.AssignedTo],
    [System.State]
From WorkItemLinks
WHERE (
        Source.[System.TeamProject] = '$projectName'
        AND Source.[System.State] <> 'Removed'
    ) AND (
        Source.[System.WorkItemType] = 'Epic')
        AND ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward'
    ) AND (Target.[System.WorkItemType] = 'UserStory') mode (Recursive)
"

$body = @{query=$query} | ConvertTo-Json
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic $base64AuthInfo")} -Body $body
```

Comment: @Srini33 You can mark it as answer if my answer solves your issue.